# Building Dataview with an Bitmap in ML.net on .net core 7 on Ubuntu

Tags: c#, ubuntu, .net-core, system.drawing, ml.net

I have the following setup:

- Ubuntu 22.04
- .NET core 7.0
- Microsoft.ML 2.0.1

I'm following some guide for ML.NET to deal with object detection(using Yolo v4). The only problem I'm dealing with it on Linux. So System.Drawing is installed as Nuget package. I have the following input data model:

```
public class ImageData
{
    [ColumnName("image")]
    [ImageType(416, 416)]
    public Bitmap Image { get; set; }

    [ColumnName("width")]
    public float ImageWidth => Image.Width;
    
    [ColumnName("height")]
    public float ImageHeight => Image.Height;
}
```

And the next ML.net pipeline:

```
        var pipeline = _mlContext.Transforms.ResizeImages(inputColumnName: "image",
                outputColumnName: "input_1:0", imageWidth: 416, imageHeight: 416,
                resizing: ImageResizingEstimator.ResizingKind.IsoPad)
            .Append(_mlContext.Transforms.ExtractPixels(outputColumnName: "input_1:0",
                scaleImage: 1f / 255f,
                interleavePixelColors: true))
            .Append(_mlContext.Transforms.ApplyOnnxModel(
                outputColumnNames: new[]
                {
                    "Identity:0",
                    "Identity_1:0",
                    "Identity_2:0"
                },
                inputColumnNames: new[]
                {
                    "input_1:0"
                },
                shapeDictionary: new Dictionary<string, int[]> {
                    { "input_1:0", new[] { 1, 416, 416, 3 } },
                    { "Identity:0", new[] { 1, 52, 52, 3, 85 } },
                    { "Identity_1:0", new[] { 1, 26, 26, 3, 85 } },
                    { "Identity_2:0", new[] { 1, 13, 13, 3, 85 } },
                },
                modelFile: yoloModelPath,
                gpuDeviceId: null,
                fallbackToCpu: true));

        var noImages = _mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(Array.Empty<ImageData>());
        return pipeline.Fit(noImages);
```

Exception:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Could not determine an IDataView type and registered custom types for member Image (Parameter 'rawType')
```

I red an articles stated that Microsoft is not supporting System.Drawing starting from .NET core 7 on other platforms then Windows. But what is an alternatives for ML.NET? Is there a way to pass in any other way to pass in an Image to ML.net other then Bitmap?